# Memory/xarray/dask bug when trying to load xarray dataset comprised of dask arrays chunks onto memory?

Tags: python, dask, python-xarray

first time posting a question so don't hesitate to point out additions/corrections if needed. Also, I am not sure if this is really a bug or not so if you think it is, I will redirect my question on the xarray/dask GitHub. I am also quite a newbie with xarray, I come from matlab but trying to transition to python. So here it is...I am opening two years of hourly data with xarray and subset it as per the code below:

```
ds=xr.open_mfdataset('F:/supdude/datatest/*', combine='by_coords')
ds=ds.sel(longitude=slice(-145+360,-52+360), latitude=slice(70,41))
```

Once done, the dataset looks like this:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:     (latitude: 117, longitude: 373, time: 17544)
Coordinates:
  * longitude   (longitude) float32 215.0 215.25 215.5 ... 307.5 307.75 308.0
  * latitude    (latitude) float32 70.0 69.75 69.5 69.25 ... 41.5 41.25 41.0
  * time        (time) datetime64[ns] 1979-01-01 ... 1980-12-31T23:00:00
Data variables:
    d2m         (time, latitude, longitude) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(8760, 117, 373), meta=np.ndarray>
```

I then proceed with simple resampling methods to bring it down to a daily basis and it comes down to this (I've got two xarray dataset that are like this):

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (latitude: 117, longitude: 373, time: 731)
Coordinates:
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 1979-01-01 1979-01-02 ... 1980-12-31
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 215.0 215.25 215.5 ... 307.5 307.75 308.0
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 70.0 69.75 69.5 69.25 ... 41.5 41.25 41.0
Data variables:
    d2m        (time, latitude, longitude) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(1, 117, 373), meta=np.ndarray>
```

The problem comes heres. I changed my resampling workflow to make it faster and I am trying to compare both results from the new resampling method and the previous one so I am sure my new method yields the right results, but in order to do that I need to load my xarray datasets onto my memory so I can access the data in the variable "d2m". To do so I use:

```
ds.load() / ds.compute()
```

When running that, I get the following memory error (full traceback at the end):

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 17.0 GiB for an array with shape (8784, 721, 1440) and data type >i2
```

This seems quite off since that is the size of a yearly file for the whole world. Technically, my datasets after resampling are supposed to be about 500 MB per year (1Gb total) and as you can see above, the full shape after resampling is (117, 373, 731) so not sure why using ".load()" yields an error with the shape (8784, 721, 1440). My computer has only 16Gb of RAM so I tried to do it on a computer that has 64Gb (so I technically should be able to open both year (17Gb per year) directly on the memory and not use dask), but when I tried to use ".load()", it filled up the whole 64Gb or RAM and crashed the computer. For now this is only a test, in the near future I'll have to deal with MUCH larger dataset so I can't really just open these up without dask on the computer that has 64Gb of RAM. Further tests showed that this problem occurs only when I already used ".load()" on an array (i.e. I want to load both my arrays to compare them, if it is in a new kernel, the first one will load up and add ~1Gb on my RAM and when I try to load up the second one, I get the memory error). I don't know a lot about dask and none of the issues I found online were directly related to what I am getting here....maybe something about the scheduler but not sure. Any ideas??

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-42-88724a7ac66e>", line 1, in <module>
    new.compute()

  File "C:\Users\Psybot\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\dataset.py", line 807, in compute
    return new.load(**kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Psybot\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\dataset.py", line 651, in load
    evaluated_data = da.compute(*lazy_data.values(), **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Psybot\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\base.py", line 437, in compute
    results = schedule(dsk, keys, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Psybot\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\threaded.py", line 84, in get
    **kwargs

  File "C:\Users\Psybot\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\local.py", line 486, in get_async
    raise_exception(exc, tb)

  File "C:\Users\Psybot\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\local.py", line 316, in reraise
    raise exc

  File "C:\Users\Psybot\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\local.py", line 222, in execute_task
    result = _execute_task(task, data)

  File "C:\Users\Psybot\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\core.py", line 118, in _execute_task
    args2 = [_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args]

  File "C:\Users\Psybot\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\core.py", line 118, in <listcomp>
    args2 = [_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args]

  File "C:\Users\Psybot\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\core.py", line 118, in _execute_task
    args2 = [_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args]

  File "C:\Users\Psybot\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\core.py", line 118, in <listcomp>
    args2 = [_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args]

  File "C:\Users\Psybot\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\core.py", line 119, in _execute_task
    return func(*args2)

  File "C:\Users\Psybot\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\array\core.py", line 106, in getter
    c = np.asarray(c)

  File "C:\Users\Psybot\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py", line 85, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)

  File "C:\Users\Psybot\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\indexing.py", line 491, in __array__
    return np.asarray(self.array, dtype=dtype)

  File "C:\Users\Psybot\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py", line 85, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)

  File "C:\Users\Psybot\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\indexing.py", line 653, in __array__
    return np.asarray(self.array, dtype=dtype)

  File "C:\Users\Psybot\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py", line 85, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)

  File "C:\Users\Psybot\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\indexing.py", line 557, in __array__
    return np.asarray(array[self.key], dtype=None)

  File "C:\Users\Psybot\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py", line 85, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)

  File "C:\Users\Psybot\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\coding\variables.py", line 72, in __array__
    return self.func(self.array)

  File "C:\Users\Psybot\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\coding\variables.py", line 218, in _scale_offset_decoding
    data = np.array(data, dtype=dtype, copy=True)

  File "C:\Users\Psybot\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\coding\variables.py", line 72, in __array__
    return self.func(self.array)

  File "C:\Users\Psybot\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\coding\variables.py", line 138, in _apply_mask
    data = np.asarray(data, dtype=dtype)

  File "C:\Users\Psybot\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py", line 85, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)

  File "C:\Users\Psybot\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\indexing.py", line 557, in __array__
    return np.asarray(array[self.key], dtype=None)

  File "C:\Users\Psybot\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\backends\netCDF4_.py", line 73, in __getitem__
    key, self.shape, indexing.IndexingSupport.OUTER, self._getitem

  File "C:\Users\Psybot\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\indexing.py", line 837, in explicit_indexing_adapter
    result = raw_indexing_method(raw_key.tuple)

  File "C:\Users\Psybot\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\backends\netCDF4_.py", line 85, in _getitem
    array = getitem(original_array, key)

  File "netCDF4\_netCDF4.pyx", line 4408, in netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable.__getitem__

  File "netCDF4\_netCDF4.pyx", line 5335, in netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable._get

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 17.0 GiB for an array with shape (8784, 721, 1440) and data type >i2
```

Comment: I recommend working to produce a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Oh, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: @MRocklin Thanks for the recommendation and sorry for the late answer. I just ended up working around the problem and segmented the whole thing to avoid any memory problem. I did more research in order to precise my question and work on an example and figured that with the little knowledge I have for the moment on dask, it would be easier/faster to just work around it.